# Python dataframe find index of top-5, then index into another column

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe, top-n

I have a dataframe with two numeric columns, A & B.  I want to find the top 5 values from col A and return the values from Col B held in the location of those top 5.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`DataFrame.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) with column `A` for top 5 rows and then select column `B`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[4,5,26,43,54,36,18,7,8,9],
                   'B':range(10)})

print (df)
    A  B
0   4  0
1   5  1
2  26  2
3  43  3
4  54  4
5  36  5
6  18  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
```

---

```
print (df.nlargest(5, 'A'))
    A  B
4  54  4
3  43  3
5  36  5
2  26  2
6  18  6

a = df.nlargest(5, 'A')['B']
print (a)
4    4
3    3
5    5
2    2
6    6
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Alternative solution with sorting:

```
a = df.sort_values('A', ascending=False)['B'].head(5)
print (a)
4    4
3    3
5    5
2    2
6    6
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @ladidalimey - Glad can help!

Answer (score 2):

`nlargest` function on the dataframe will do your work, `df.nlargest(#of rows,'column_to_sort')`

```
import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4],'B':[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,1]})
df.nlargest(5,'B')
Out[13]: 
    A      B
6   2      4
2   1      3
5   2      3
1   1      2
4   2      2
# if you want only certain column in the output, the use

df.nlargest(5,'B')['A']
```